# Is there a regex expression in Google Analytics to filter keywords that contain an upper-case letter?

Tags: regex, google-analytics

Looking to build a segment in Google Analytics that contains keywords that do not have any upper-case letters.

For example,

```
price of a Hilton room     | should be excluded as it has an upper-case letter
price of a hilton room     | should be included as it has no upper-case letters
PRICE OF A HILTON room     | should be excluded as it has upper-case letters
price of a $12 hilton room | should be included as it has no upper-case letters
```

my segment with the regex seems to remove everything:

```
Keyword DOES NOT MATCH REGEX [A-Z]
```

I've also tried this which doesn't seem to remove keywords with upper case:

```
Keyword DOES NOT MATCH REGEX [^$0-9a-z ]
```

Comment: Try `Keyword DOES NOT MATCH REGEX [[:upper:]]` or `Keyword DOES NOT MATCH REGEX \p{Lu}`

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
/^[^A-Z]+$/gm
```

explanation

```
first ^ : match the beginning
[^A-Z] : any character except A-Z range
+ : 1 or more characters
$ : match the end
gm : global and multiple lines
```

result : 
[image]

Comment: thanks aziz but unfortunately that seems to exlcude all keywords in Google Analytics. I'm not sure the if the version of regex in GA can handle things like "gm" as it doesn't appear in the reference here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034324?hl=en&ref_topic=1034375